# Sum of n number inside array is x number and create subset of result

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, data-structures

For example, if you have an array [20, 6, 7, 8, 50] and if I pass value 21 it should return [6,7,8] this sub array. Note: the sum of number should be in sequence.

```
[20, 6, 7, 8, 50]
21 - [6, 7, 8]
13 - [6, 7]
50 - [] - because it is not in sequence
```

I tried but not working

```
function sumoftwonumer(arr, s) {
    let hashtable = {}
    let sum = []
    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        let innerRequiredValue = s - arr[i] 
        if(hashtable[innerRequiredValue.toString()] !== undefined) {
            sum.push([arr[i], innerRequiredValue])
        }
        hashtable[innerRequiredValue.toString()] = arr[i]
    }
    console.log(hashtable)
    return sum
}
```

Comment: So the sequence has to have more than one element?  Otherwise, `50` should return `[50]`.

Comment: yes 50 return 50

Comment: is 50 in sequence or not? it's a single value...

Comment: 50 is not sequence

Comment: do you have negative numbers?

Comment: Yes may be, given solution work for me

Comment: I'm afraid your comments are not clear.  what should `sumoftwonumbers([20, 6, 7, 8, 50], 50)` return?  Is it `[]` or `[50]`?

Comment: It should return []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using nested for loop. The time complexity in worst case will `O(n^2)`. Make sure to see the second method its more efficient.

```js
let arr = [20, 6, 7, 8, 50]

function findNums(arr,sum){
  let temp = 0;
  for(let i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
    temp = arr[i];
    for(let j = i+1;j<arr.length;j++){
      temp += arr[j];
      if(temp === sum) return arr.slice(i,j+1);
      if(temp > sum) break;
    }
  }
  return [];
}

console.log(findNums(arr,21))
console.log(findNums(arr,13))
console.log(findNums(arr,50))
```

A better solution is what create a variable `temp`. Start adding elements to it one by one. When it becomes greater than given sum then remove the element from start of array.

```js
let arr = [20, 6, 7, 8, 50]

function findNums(arr,sum){
  let temp = arr[0];
  let low = 0;
  for(let i = 1;i<arr.length;i++){
    temp += arr[i];
    if(temp === sum) return arr.slice(low,i+1);
    while(temp > sum){
      temp -= arr[low]
      low++;
    }
  }
  return [];
}

console.log(findNums(arr,21))
console.log(findNums(arr,13))
console.log(findNums(arr,50))
```

#### For Negative Numbers

The problem with negative numbers is that we can't remove elements from start when the `temp`(current sum) becomes greater than given sum because we may have so negative numbers after in array which could make `temp` less than or equal to sum

For negative number you need to create an object to keep track of already calculated sums of subarrays.

```js
let arr = [4,-2,-3,5,1,10]

function findNums(arr,sum){
  let obj = {}
  let temp = 0;
  for(let i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
    temp += arr[i];
    if(temp === sum) return arr.slice(0,i+1);
    if(obj[temp - sum] != undefined){
      if(obj[temp-sum]+1 !== i){
        return arr.slice(obj[String(temp - sum)]+1,i+1);
      }
    }
    obj[temp] = i;
  }
  return [];
}


console.log(findNums(arr,0))
console.log(findNums(arr,-1))
console.log(findNums(arr,13))
console.log(findNums(arr,1))
```

Comment: @ChandanKumar Check out the other solution I just added. Its time complexity is `O(n)`

Comment: @NinaScholz You are right. I updated with a solution for negative numbers. Please check it

Answer (score 1):

One possibility, depending upon how you want to use it, is to do as your attempt seems to try, and create a hashmap of partial sums, returning a function that will lookup in that hashmap for your value.  Here, I do that, making the function curried so that you don't have to go to all the work of creating a hashmap for one set of numbers on every call.

The initial call is `O(n^2)`, but subsequent calls are merely `O(1)`.  This style is useful if you want to search multiple values on the same set of numbers.  If you only have one value to search, then a technique like the second one in Maheer Ali's answer would be more efficient.

```js
const range = (lo, hi) => [...Array (hi - lo) ]
  .map ( (_, i) => lo + i )
const sum = (nbrs) => 
  nbrs .reduce ( (a, b) => a + b, 0 )

const findSequentialSum = (nbrs) => {
  const subtotals = range (0, nbrs .length)
    .flatMap (
      i => range (i + 2, nbrs .length + 1)
        .map (j => nbrs .slice (i, j) )
    ) 
    // .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [[]])
    .reduce ( 
      (a, sub, _, __, tot = sum(sub) ) => ({
        ...a, 
        [tot]: a [tot] || sub
      }),
      {}
    )
  return (total) => subtotals [total] || []
}

const nbrs = [20, 6, 7, 8, 50]

const search = findSequentialSum (nbrs)

console .log (
  search (21), //~> [6, 7, 8]
  search (13), //~> [6, 7]
  search (50), //~> []
)
```

The two helper functions should be straightforward: `range(3, 10) //=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` and `sum([2, 5, 10]) //=> 17`

If [`flatMap` isn't available](https://caniuse.com/#search=flatmap) in your environment, then you can replace

```js
    .flatMap (
      i => range (i + 2, nbrs .length + 1)
        .map (j => nbrs .slice (i, j) )
    )
```

with

```js
    .map (
      i => range (i + 2, nbrs .length + 1)
        .map (j => nbrs .slice (i, j) )
    ) 
    .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [[]])
```

Also, the `2` in here

```js
      i => range (i + 2, nbrs .length + 1)
```

requires sequences to be at least two entries long.  If you wanted `50` to return `[50]` (which seems more logical to me), then you could just replace that `2` with a `1`.  Or you could replace it with something larger, if you wanted to find only sub-sequences of, say, length 5 or more.

Finally, if you wanted to return *all* subsequences that added to your total, it would be a simple modification, replacing:

```js
        [tot]: a [tot] || sub
```

with

```js
        [tot]: (a [tot] || []).concat([sub])
```